# Handshake failed due to invalid Connection header [Keep-Alive]

Tags: websocket, weblogic12c, spring-websocket, sslhandshakeexception

I have a websocket project, develop it on Weblogic 12c and Spring MVC 5.1.0.RELEASE

When i running project on local tomcat, its working normally, but when trying to deploy on Weblogic, its gave below error. (Error only occurs with secure domain, when i tried to on http adress with ip its working good.)

```
Apr 09, 2021 2:28:57 PM org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler handleInvalidConnectHeader
SEVERE: Handshake failed due to invalid Connection header [Keep-Alive]
<Apr 9, 2021 2:28:57 PM GMT+03:00> <Error> <org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler> <BEA-000000> <Handshake failed due to invalid Connection header [Keep-Alive]>
```

My headers;

```
 - Sec-WebSocket-Version : 13
 - Sec-WebSocket-Key : MoTfrW6Iim1noQgYHlkeYQ==
 - Upgrade : websocket
 - Cookie : jwt=eyJhbGciO....
 - Sec-WebSocket-Extensions : permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
 - Host : blabla.com.tr
 - ECID-Context : 1.005jsZwLhO_EoIWVLynJ8A0001Cy0000i2;kXjE
 - Connection : Keep-Alive
 - X-WebLogic-KeepAliveSecs : 30
 - X-WebLogic-Force-JVMID : -414283189
 - X-WebLogic-Request-ClusterInfo : true
```

My implementation something like;

```
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
   registry.addHandler(new EchoHandler(), "/echo").addInterceptors(customHandshakeInterceptor())
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
```

Testing with;

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:8080/projectName/echo --no-color
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the value for Connection header to 'Upgrade';